# Commons DBUtils Oracle 11g Prepared Statement - Insert statement

Tags: java, mysql, oracle, oracle11g, apache-commons-dbutils

I am unsing Commons DBUtils Oracle 11g Prepared Statement to insert values in my database.

My syntax resembles the following: `insert into tablename (col_names) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )`

I have 10 columns. I am using ? to fill params at runtime.

When I run QueryRunner.insert command I get an exception that it is expecting 11 parameters and I am providing 10. ( the count 11 is coming from some internal class that is setting its count_param to be 11 - I could not figure why)

**Is this syntax correct for insert statement?**

Comment: can you execute `java -classpath <path-to-your-ojdbc.jar>  oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleParameterMetaDataParser "<your sql stmt>"` and show the result?

Comment: If you're using Oracle 11g why have you included a MySQL tag? Please don't be confusing.

Answer (score 0):

That syntax is correct for an INSERT statement in MySQL.

I'd recommend using this as a reference in the future http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/

Comment: Also, SQL GUI tools like MySQLWorkbench (<https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/>) are worth looking into, as they allow you to test your queries outside of your code.